How is ASP.NET (or any other) Web API server built?
I wonder if there is any scheme, diagram or book that would explain how are Web API servers built?
I am talking about deeper stuff like for example how is threadpool built, routing table and other stuff that I probably don't know.
I cannot find any information on the web, only thing I get is how businesses stuff is being built but I am talking about architecture behind server itself.

Most of these frameworks are open-source.  You can literally download the source and step through them.   "how to build a http server" is way beyond a stack-overflow posting, but a quick google search will point you in the right direction.
I'd start by understanding the base HTTP servers in any given framework, then understanding how they are leveraged in the higher-level API server projects by looking at the source for those projects.
